# Add New Table Columns Conditionally

Tags: powerbi, dax

Im using PowerBI and I want to create a new table from an existing table that has already been imported to PowerBI. The imported table is shown below:

[image]

I want the new table to appear as follows:

[image]

Comment: Did it work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerQuery to do it when you do the loading/importing to Power BI:

- Name the query to load the table “Original”
- Duplicate the query and name it “Pivot”

In Query “Pivot”:

- Delete column [LOC]
- Pivot column [UNIT] with [Value] as the value column

In the query “Original”:

- Merge queries with the table/query “Pivot” on column [FY]
- Expand with the desired columns from the latter
- Delete the unwanted columns

This can be done without any coding just selecting the steps in PowerQuery.

(You can combine the underlying M code into one query if you are familiar with coding in the Advanced Editor. Basically, having the second query nested in the first one.)

Good luck!

Pivot: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/pivot-columns

Merge: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/merge-queries-overview